# which is best to add a datasource and delegate for like table view storyboard or code

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, storyboard

which is best to add a datasource and delegate for like table view and others storyboard or code.

StoryBoard or Code which is best to add datasource and delegate.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: All of them. They're the same type.

Comment: its all depend on you how you like and which one is more preferable for your working style

Comment: Try to work on code.

Comment: @Taimoor Suleman Why Try To Work On Code...????

Comment: because sometimes storyboard is responding well and storyboard is very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are best.

Code: We need to write a code say for example:
[tableView setDelegate:(id)self];
[tableView setDatasource:(id)self];

Storyboard: We need to simply connect delegate & datasource to filesource

According to me Storyboard is good as line of code will decrease from the project.